# In a Spring webmvc project, use a extern folder for the templates

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, configuration, thymeleaf

I have tried to externalize the template folder of my spring webmvc proyect, I need this feature because the designer want to modify very often the html. And is to dificult for him to edit inside de a war file. I use thymeleaf as templateResolver

```
<bean id="templateResolver" 
    class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">

    <property name="prefix" value="file:/opt/templates/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
    <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
    <property name="cacheable" value="false" />
</bean>
```

I tried using this line, but it didn't work

```
<property name="prefix" value="file:/opt/templates/" />
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You cannot change that while the application is running.

Comment: Are you sure?, I made the cacheable false. But my real problem is the aplication didn't find the templates, it don't understand the "file:/" part

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `FileTemplateResolver` instead of `ServletContextTemplateResolver`.

Try this:

```
<bean id="templateResolver" 
    class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.FileTemplateResolver">

    <property name="prefix" value="/opt/templates/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
    <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
    <property name="cacheable" value="false" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Windows user can have prefix value like "/c:/myfolder/templates/". I wasted a lot of time by using "file:/c:/myfolder/templates/" :-)

Answer (score 1):

The class version :

```
@Configuration
public class TemplateEngineConfig {
    @Value("${templates.path}")
    private String HTML_TEMPLATES_PATH;

    @Bean
    public TemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        TemplateEngine templateEngine = new TemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        return templateEngine;
    }

    private TemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        TemplateResolver resolver = new FileTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/opt/templates/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setCacheable(false);
        return resolver;
    }
}
```